# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values - dataGridView maskedTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am trying to host a masked textbox in a dataGridView column. The user is supposed to enter valid date values in the format dd/mm/year and i was following the example here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26005/DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox

However, am having trouble with the piece of code below. I have rows pre-populated and the user is supposed to update the Date column only, which is by default NULL in the database.

When i click in the column to put it in edit mode, i get the error message

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values at line `if (Value == null || Value is DBNull)`

below is the problematic piece of code and exception snapshot screenshot

```
 public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
        MaskedEditEditingControl editingControl = base.DataGridView.EditingControl as MaskedEditEditingControl;
        if (editingControl != null)
        {
            if (Value == null || Value is DBNull)
                editingControl.Text = (string)DefaultNewRowValue;
            else
                switch (Value.GetType().FullName)
                {
                    case "System.DateTime":
                        DateTime dt = (DateTime)Value;
                        editingControl.Text = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm");
                        break;
                    case "System.String":
                        editingControl.Text = (string)Value;
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug where it .NET sometimes uses the incorrect rowIndex within the DataGridViewCell.Value property accessor.  We can't easily see inside that or do anything about it.

I hit this same problem.  For me it's fine at first but when moving into another cell, the error happens. I'm working with the DataGridView in virtual mode but this may not be relevant.

You can work around it fairly easily by substituting the cells GetValue() function in place of the Value property.

```
    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
       //... 
       //DateTime dt = (DateTime)this.Value;
       DateTime dt = (DateTime)this.GetValue(rowIndex);
       //...
    }
```

You might also consider sanitising the return value as it's not guaranteed to be of the correct type or range.

I realise it's a late for this question but hopefully it can help someone else.